# Adding another link after id does not trigger child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying out angular-ui-router's child state and I want to add another link after an id but it doesn't seem to trigger. Example would be:

Parent url: `parent/:id`

Child url: `parent/:id/child`

Here's a plunker of my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/kspeIoA8mB3vrAsLJpSe?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `ui-sref` as

`ui-sref='parent.child({id:15})'`

here is [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OSD3HPR973iWw0OHlmkK?p=preview)

from your plunker **parent.html**

```
<p> I am the parent dude! </p>
<a ui-sref='parent.child({id:15})'> A link to my child </a>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

[Ui-sref api references](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

Comment: What seems to be the problem with the first one? The `parent.index` worked like a charm, and so with `parent/:id`

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the url. It appends to the current one.